# error with Nullpointer exeption string in datasnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question has been asked in the past. I have tried almost all of their solutions did not worked for me. Sorry for asking this again. But can someone help me fix this error.

> Here is my code.

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView userEmail;
TextView userID;
TextView userGender;
TextView userName;
Button userLogout;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    userEmail = findViewById(R.id.tvUserEmail);
    userGender = findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
    userName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    userID = findViewById(R.id.tvUserID);
    userLogout = findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(firebaseUser.getUid());

    //userEmail.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String userEmailstr = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
            String userNamestr = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String userGenderstr = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
            String userIDstr = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString();


            userEmail.setText(userEmailstr);
            userGender.setText(userGenderstr);
            userName.setText(userNamestr);
            userID.setText(userIDstr);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    userLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

The error is on the Datasnapshot Strings. where it is said it is on a null object reference

> Here is the logcat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.patrick.test.ProfileActivity$1.onDataChange(ProfileActivity.java:60)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
```

> Here is my database
>   [image]

Comment: Which is the line 60 in this code?

Comment: String userNamestr = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

Comment: show your Database.

Comment: I suspect your key `name` not to be available or has another name in the database...

Comment: I edited it. check it out.

Comment: You're trying to use a UID to access the data, but that key in the database you think is a UID is not acutally a UID.  It's a push ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whe you are using:

```
.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
```

It means that you are passing to the child method the id of the user that is coming from the Firebase authentication process. But passing this id will not help since in your database I see that you are having an id that is generated by the `push()` method and **not** the id from the `FirebaseUser` object.

So to solve this, you either pass to the `child()` method the correct id which is `-LS3X ... 6Meg` or you change the way in which you are adding the user to database by removing the `push()` call and use something like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("Accounts").child(uid).setValue(userObject);
```

The second solution is the recommended one. Please also don't forget to add the `Accounts` extra child that is missing right now from your reference.

Comment: Thank you so very much! been stuck with that problem for days.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(firebaseUser.getUid());
```

To

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Accounts").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
```

You're pointing to wrong node. that doesn't contains required data.

**Note:**

You don't need to store `push_id` inside as `id`.

You can simply get it without storing it inside.

```
String userIDstr = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but it is still the same error.

Comment: this should work. have you added `google-service.json` to your `app folder` ?

Comment: Yes. I already did that, and downloaded a new google-service.json and copied it to my app folder.

Comment: Can you debug it. Check where it is throwing error.

Comment: I dont know how. Sorry... Just started with coding and firebase.

Comment: Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.patrick.test.ProfileActivity$1.onDataChange(ProfileActivity.java:59) Where line 59 is String userEmailstr = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(firebaseUser.getUid())
```

To

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Accounts").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
```

And instead of

```
String userEmailstr = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
```

Use

```
String userEmailstr = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. The error is gone but there is no display text in the app.

Comment: Please make sure that you have child and values with that userID in your firebase database